# Monitor resolution too high and not saving

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I've just started using Elementary OS, and I'm having a bit of trouble with the resolution saving. My monitor/tv's native resolution is 4K, but I prefer to run in 1080p. When the login screen boots up, it's always in 4K, then when I login, I have to change to 1080p, it never saves. The other thing is that when I change the resolution to 1080p, the mouse cursor is huge because it is the 4K mouse cursor. Could anyone give me a bit of help? Other than that I'm pretty happy with the operating system as a whole. Few bits here and there but overall okay.

Answer (score 0):

what graphics card do you have, which version of ElementaryOS are you running

You can use the following command in the terminal to decide which graphics card you have

sudo lspci|grep VGA

To me it seems like a driver issue so the answer about it depends on the card and driver you are using.

Comment: I forgot to add, write which one you have here and i will reply with a proper response as soon as possible

Comment: Hi there, thanks for taking the time to Answer. I'm running the latest version (elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20170814)01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1). Card is an MSI NVIDIA GTX 1070. I saved the X configuration file into my x.org folder and now when I load the logon is at the correct resolution (1080p), but when I log in, it's back to 4k resolution, and every time I have to change it. However, the fact that the login is now in 1080p, the mouse cursor problem is fixed.

Comment: Have you installed the nvidia driver? or are you using the built in noveau driver? Cause sometimes a driver update can fix the issue

Comment: I'm using the NVIDIA driver. It's NVIDIA settings that I'm using to set the resolution, just it won't save upon restart.

Comment: Try and take a look at this thread then, I have had similar issues and used that to fix it

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/746125/screen-resolution-is-not-saved-after-reboot